# How to maintain the position of ListView

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)

How can I maintain the position of my ListView in my activity when I go to another activity (by launching another intent) and then come back (press the back button)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

Declare global variables:

```
int index = 0;
ListView list;
```

and make a reference to your `ListView` in `onCreate()`:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
```

Next, in `onResume()`, add this line at the end:

```
list.setSelectionFromTop(index, 0);
```

Lastly, in `onPause`, add the following line to the end:

```
index = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Comment: Furthermore, I would save the index in a sharedPreferences object so that when the application goes out of scope, it still retains the index

Comment: @mray190 that is what saving the instance state is for. You can save this value in a bundle on orientation changes then restore the scrolled state when the view is recreated, at an Activity or Fragment level.

Answer (score 7):

Do simple....

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
   index = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
   // store index using shared preferences   
}
```

and..

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
// get index from shared preferences

if(listView != null){
    if(listView.getCount() > index)
        listView.setSelectionFromTop(index, 0);
    else
        listView.setSelectionFromTop(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: An explanation of the code may have helped.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `onSaveInstanceState` to store the scroll position and then use either `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState` to restore it.

[http://developer.android.com...#onSaveInstanceState...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: I tried your way.  mListView.getSelectedItemPosition(); return me a -1 and mListView.getScrollY() give me a 0.  I am clearly scroll down to my ListView when I do my test. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: What did you do to try my way?

Comment: I did:
 protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     int scroll = mListView.getScrollY();
        System.out.println (" scrollY" + scroll);
}

Comment: Ah, I have no idea.  I haven't used a listView yet.  I'm just starting on android.

Comment: Does it work when called from onPause?

Comment: No. It also gives me 0 when I call  mListView.getScrollY().

Comment: That is the wrong method. You should have been storing myListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() in onPause(), then restoring that position with myListView.setSelection(). Where you store that int is up to you depending on whether you want it to persist after destroy

Answer (score 2):

Please note that using ListView.getScrollY() DOES NOT WORK WELL for restoring the scroll position.

See [Android: ListView.getScrollY() - does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132370/android-listview-getscrolly-does-it-work)

> It is referring to the scroll amount of the entire view, so it will almost always be 0.

It happened to me too most of the time that this value was 0. 
ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() with ListView.setSelection() works more reliably.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    // Save scroll position
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SCROLL", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    int scroll = mListView.getScrollY();
    editor.put("ScrollValue", scroll);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    // Get the scroll position
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SCROLL", 0);
    int scroll = preferences.getInt("ScrollView", 0);
    mListView.scrollTo(0, scroll);
}
```

Comment: If I use 'getSharedPreferences', does it mean it will persist to the disk? i.e. it will preserve the value after I reboot the phone? What if I don't want that? when I reboot the phone, it will start from 0?

Comment: It will persist beyond shutdown.  If you do not want that then you can write the value to a member variable and hope that it persists.  It should if the app doesn't get garbage collected.  You just need to decide which side you'd like to err on.

Comment: I think line 6 in the onPause should read editor.putInt("ScrollValue", scroll);

Comment: mListView.getScrollY() returns 0 , always. read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132370/android-listview-getscrolly-does-it-work