# How to retain Android ListView scroll position when returning to an activity?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)

The user views a listview of items, they move to an activity that shows detail for one item, and then hit Back and return to the list activity but I want the list to reflect its prior scroll position.

Should I store the scroll position as a member variable on the activity in onPause or is there a better way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Save the position in an instance variable on onPause and in onResume check if there is position value and move to it.

e.g. using

```
private int currentPostion;
```

and then in onResume do..

```
getListView().setSelection(currentPosition);
```

Comment: You should also consider putting this value in the `Bundle` passed to `onSaveInstanceState()` and use it in `onRestoreInstanceState()`, so you can handle orientation changes.

Comment: Thanks Manfred and Mark, all working well, appreciate the help.

Comment: that is working fine. but I am using second activity - semi transparent. so scroll view first come to the top then after pressing back from second activity scroll view comes at it place.

Comment: sorry.. but your comment does not make sense. Ask a separate questions maybe.

Comment: This will not preserve an exact scroll position.

Comment: Not sure what you mean Sver. It works just fine for me on multiple lists. Unless of course you mean pixel perfect scroll position.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is what Sver meant, Manfred. You method will only scroll to the post's top edge. Most apps, for example Google+, use a more professional method to restore the position, which CommonsWare explained.

Comment: Marks remark is just required so that pausing and screen rotations and such do not cause issue and is of course also good to do but thats a separate topic to the question.