# How to implement a proper scroll in list view to implement pagination on fragment activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, pagination

I am building an application like techcrunch. I am fetching data from server in JSON format and displaying the data in list view like article title,author name and image. I have applied pagination means when user scroll more articles load in a list view. My pagination works fine but there is an issue in the scroll function as the fresh or new data loads the scroll dose not aligns with the data. To clarify more in simple words my scroll-er goes at the top of the page when i am actually scrolling down this is my code :

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

public OneFragment(){}
private static final String TAG = OneFragment.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static String URL = "http:url&page=1";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
int current_page = 1;
int mPreLast;
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swip, container, false);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);


    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list49);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
        {
            int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
               if(lastItem == totalItemCount){
                   if (mPreLast != lastItem)
                   {
                       mPreLast = lastItem;
                       onStart();

                   }
            }
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>  adapterView, View view, int Position,
                long offset)  { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Movie item = (Movie) adapter.getItem(Position);             
            Intent intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), SingleArticle.class);
            single.date = item.getDate();
            single.id = item.getId();


            startActivity(intent);


            }        
        });
    //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    // calling adapter changes here, just
    // to avoid getactivity()null
    // increment current page
    current_page += 1;

    // Next page request
    URL = "http:url&page=" + current_page;
    //adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);

    // changing action bar color
    //getActivity().getActionBar().setBackground(
            //new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setDate(obj.getString("date"));
                            movie.setId(obj.getString("id"));

                            movieList.add(movie);
                            int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("No Connectivity ")
                    .setMessage("Please check your internet connectivity!")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                            // continue with delete
                        }
                     })
                    //.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        //public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                            // do nothing
                        //}
                     //})
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                     .show();
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);    
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private View getActionBar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
if (pDialog != null) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    pDialog = null;
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (I added a line to set the new list position in the last line of onStart())

With this line you can set the new position_

`listView.setSelectionFromTop(newPosition, 0);`
With the first parameter you set the position, and with the second you set the distnace from the top of the list

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
super.onStart();
// calling adapter changes here, just
// to avoid getactivity()null
// increment current page
current_page += 1;

// Next page request
URL = "http:url&page=" + current_page;
//adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);

// changing action bar color
//getActivity().getActionBar().setBackground(
        //new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

// Creating volley request obj
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.setDate(obj.getString("date"));
                        movie.setId(obj.getString("id"));

                        movieList.add(movie);
                        int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }                       
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("No Connectivity ")
                .setMessage("Please check your internet connectivity!")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                 })
                //.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    //public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // do nothing
                    //}
                 //})
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                 .show();
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);    
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//Set the new position
listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition  + 1, 0);
 }
```