# Android - Java ListView Item Order

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

im currently learning to programm apps for Android. So im trying to programm a little app, that allows u to add and delete items to a ListView.

It currently looks like [image: this]:

I want the items in the ListView to stay at the top, like 
[image: this]

Im sorry for my English, thats why i tried to express it with the pictures. I hope u understood what my problem is.

Thats what the Java Code looks like at the moment, not much, no Listener added yet. Im just trying to find out how to make it look better at the moment:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvItems = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.listView);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add("First Item");
    items.add("Second Item");
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items );
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}
```

and this is the XML Code at the moment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="Enter a new Item" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:gravity="top"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You may found solution here [Retaining position in ListView after calling notifyDataSetChanged][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276128/retaining-position-in-listview-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged

Comment: Does you `ListView` take all available space - did you use `android:layout_height="match_parent"`? Anyway, let us see your layout xml so we don't have to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah... I just realised how stupid i am for missing this easy fix :O Thx guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

To your listView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.reverse(yourarraylist);`

For this approach you can change list order