# Error setSelectionFromTop() requires API level 21 (current min. is 10)

Tags: android, api

I'm getting an error after using this 
[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8276140/5162360):

> `setSelectionFromTop()` requires API level 21 (current min. is 10)

and When I checked android API, it was added in API Level 1. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

After some googling it seams that yeah, it's a bug...

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172621

Comment: so what ?!! we need to wait google to solve APIs :D ?!!

Answer (score 0):

As @pelotasplus says it's a bug and seems google still doesn't solve it till now. You can add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` annotation to prevent lint check. See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html#src