# Android ViewPager with ListView can not remember the last position when called notifyDatasetchanged

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I'm a Chinese and my English is poor. I met a problem when I use the `ViewPager` with the `ListView` (`ListView` added in `ViewPager`) and `PagerAdapter` mode is POSITION_NONE, I saved the inflated `ListView` with List in PagerAdapter but the strange phenomenon is when I call the pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged the `ListView` scroll to the first position.Here is the code:

```
private class MyAdapter2 extends PagerAdapter {


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        container.addView(listviews[position], 0);

        return listviews[position];
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sunshine,
when ever you refresh the parent layout child layout also will refresh that is the reason your listview also refreshing. (As per my view).

Comment: but i save every page in pageAdapter when the view is inflated,such as the first listview and will not inflate the xml except the first time in instantiateItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this logic... before call dataSetChanged store this listview state in `Parcelable` varaiable  and after dataSetChanged time for restore the listview from  a value which you have  strored in a parcelable variable 
like this ..

```
   Parcelable scrollPos=listview.onSaveInstanceState();
   // call your pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged 

    if(scrollPos != null)
    {
        listview.onRestoreInstanceState(scrollPos);    
    }
```

there is another way i found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276128/retaining-position-in-listview-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged)

```
    // save index and top position
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// notify dataset changed or re-assign adapter here

// restore the position of listview
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Comment: thank you very much,but the first way seems not work for me