# Listview scroll to bottom

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I want a whatsapp like download image feature if i download an image and when download complete the list position does not change.Every thing is working fine but when download complete the listview scrolls to bottom.

Comment: This question has been addressed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7032341/1394695

Comment: Just put the scrollMyListViewToBottom() method from my link in the appropriate place (e.g. some callback method).

Comment: @Nisha Every time u will getting new data in array list ?? 
Or when user can scroll down that a time user can getting new data every time? so u can use PullToReferesh Lib.

Comment: I have a list view which can contains text or image(some static image) , and on image i have a download button , when i click on download button image is download and its local path is saved in database. 
If i call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); , but when i scroll the listview the image just changed to default pic.
or if i use list.setAdapter(adapter); then the listview scrolls to bottom.

Comment: I want that the image should be change but list should not scrolls to bottom. like a whatsapp if i download an image when download complete the list position does not change.

Comment: already used  android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
   android:stackFromBottom="true" , but it does not works.

Comment: using chatList.setSelectionFromTop(index,top);  i have resolved my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retaining position in ListView after calling notifyDataSetChanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276128/retaining-position-in-listview-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged)

Comment: chatList.setSelectionFromTop(index,top); will works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276128/retaining-position-in-listview-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged

Answer (score 0):

To update the listview contents, Call adapter.notifydatasetchanged(). Where adapter is the one which is set for your litview.

Comment: But notifydatasetchanged will not cause the list to be scrolled down...

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding this method to your own use. I have modified it to suit my custom layout manager for a recycler view but the same can be done for a list view. You can find loads of tutorials on google.

```
@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                   RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller =
            new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {

                //This controls the direction in which smoothScroll looks
                //for your view
                @Override
                public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition
                (int targetPosition) {
                    return FoodFragmentCustomLayoutManager.this
                            .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                }

                //This returns the milliseconds it takes to
                //scroll one pixel.
                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                }
            };

    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}
```

Comment: put the layout inside a CoordinatorLayout for it to work properly **

Comment: i want  a whatsapp  like download image feature if i download an image and when download complete the list position does not change.Every thing is working fine but when download complete the listview scrolls to bottom.

Comment: when the download completes, call smoothScrollToPosition(positionyouwant)

Comment: i have used following on itemclicklistener of listview :-
adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(mcon, messages);
chatList.setAdapter(adapter);
chatList.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
if (arg2 <= chatList.getFirstVisiblePosition() || arg2 >= chatList.getLastVisiblePosition()) {
chatList.smoothScrollToPosition(arg2);
}
But again the scrollview moves to bottom.

Comment: chatList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(arg2, 0); works but it looks very weird as fluctuation in listview when download complete . it should be at the same position where it is before downloading.

Comment: chatList.setSelectionFromTop(index,top); will works.

Comment: I am not aware of that method, sorry :( Anyway if that helps your cause better, use it :) If scrolling to zero looks weird, you can save the list size before updating and then update data set. Then immediately set smoothscroll to position to the saved list size and it should get you to where you were previously.

Comment: Yea checked it out, mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top); will work :) Use my method for some other cause. It's a cool way to take someone to what they are searching ;) i use it for that :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276128/retaining-position-in-listview-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged the perfect answer you want :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: today , while testing the app i was again getting error of image changed to default image when scroll in list. mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top) stops working now