# Get LinearLayout position in a Scroll Layout android

Tags: android, scroll

I have a scroll view with a linear layout inside, which contains many text boxes.

Now I'm trying to build up an automatic scrolling, but I can't get the current scroll position of the layout.

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

<s>Check out this answer, I think it's the thing you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/375929</s>

**Edit:**

How about doing this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("scrollX", scrollView.getScrollX());
    outState.putInt("scrollY", scrollView.getScrollY());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    int scrollX = savedInstanceState.getInt("scrollX"); // Defaults to 0
    int scrollY = savedInstanceState.getInt("scrollY");
    scrollView.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but list view is a whole other thing.