# Listview getFirstVisiblePosition

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the position of the first visible row that is entirely visible to screen.  End of scrolling, if the portion of the row is visible in first row, I need to select next position. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = list.getChildAt(0);
int y = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

if (y > 0 && index + 1 < list.getCount()) {
    ++index;
}
```

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/165674).

Comment: This seems to work for me. But still I needed only the value for "y". So I didn't try the last if condition.Apart from that, the condition seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

youe need to implement `OnScrollListener` on your ListView and then override the following method to get the first visible item:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
    //"firstVisibleItem" is the value you need to look for
}
```

Comment: but i want to check ,whether the user can see the first row (firstVisibleItem) entirely. for example when you started scroll a list, you can see only little part in first row & last row. if you want to see entire portion of the first/bottom row, you need to scroll it up/down little future.

Comment: as long as even 1dp of an item is visible, it is considered as visible by `firstVisibleItem`