# ListView get scroll position?

Tags: android

I'm using a MergeAdapter (from Mark Murphy's excellent series of projects). You use it with a ListView. I'm trying to rebuild the contents of the adapter on a refresh (instead of refreshing "in place" and calling notifyDataSetChange()).

I'd like to get the y-scroll value of the listview so I can reset to that after I rebuild my list. This doesn't seem to be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement OnScrollListener for your listview.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) { 
//firstvisible is your first visible item in the list
}
```

Comment: Right but that doesn't tell us the exact scroll position in pixels, right? I want to call ListView.scrollTo(x, y) after I refresh my list. But the OnScrollListener just tells you the visible items, not their position or anything.

Comment: Check out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/scroll-to-a-position-in-a-listview

Comment: Does not work : onScroll only work for views like ScrollView.

Comment: The correct [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727594/android-listview-current-scroll-location-y-pixels/35594825#35594825)