# Saving scroll position in the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)

how to save scroll position in the ListView? I should to add elements into the head of the ListView and into an arbitrary position, but visual part should NOT be scrolled.

for example I have 123 elements, I see 1/2 part of the element with index 66 (elements have a different height). I added an element into the list, and I should to see 1/2 part of the element with index 67 (previously index 66).

you can see as example - default "SMS" application for windows phone 7.5. This application uses the lazy-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  `getSelection()` and `setSelection()` method

Get the current selection using `getSelection()` and when you comes back to that ListView again the call  `setSelection()`

Comment: it's not worked for me... android 2.3.3

Comment: Sorry, it's worked, if I use this setter as myListView.post(new Runnable ...setSelection()...);. but after the notifyDataChanged scroll setted into the 0 position (visually), and setted to my position later. scroll position will not be stored :(