# Android activity not holding place.

Tags: android

im kinda new to android and i am following a the google dev blogs, and tutorials on Lynda.com and i encountered an issue which i can't seem to find a solution for.

I have a ListView full of items , and on click it will load a new Activity. 
all of that works as expected. But when i click back on the new activity the parent loads up as if it were entirely new. back at the top of the list view.

Lets say i scroll down to the middle somewhere. I click an item, i get the results whatever, I go back to parent and then i am back at list item (0) again.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWAQ6.jpg

how would i go about it keeping its position on back press?

thanks

Comment: Take a look: [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)

Comment: Try something like [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11187909/1289716)

Answer (score 1):

You can help your self with this thread: [Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561353/programmatically-scroll-to-a-specific-position-in-an-android-listview)

You should remember the position at which you where when you selected the element. And when you go back, you should set that position with:

```
getListView().setSelection(21);
```

Comment: Agree please add, he also need to save selection first :)

Comment: i'll try this out when i get back home.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688490/4894540) 
The idea is to save the state of your listView when you exit the activity and then restore it :

```
Parcelable state;

@Override
public void onPause(){
    state = yourListView.onSaveInstanceState();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    //reload data if needed
    if(state != null) {
        yourListView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        state = null;
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Hope it helps !