# how to scroll to particular item in listview based on text entered in edittext?

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have created a multiple contacts picker in which i am showing list of all the contacts in the `listview` with `checkbox`, but what i want to do is that now i want to place one `edittext` at the top so as to allow user to scroll through the list quickly. For example if user types letter D in the `edittext` it should scroll down to the position where names starts with D. I am using `CustomAdapter` to fill the data in the list.

Comment: @Eric i didnt get what you are trying to say?

Comment: Have you done any research into how you would accomplish this? We're not here to just hand out code snippets, we want to see you make an effort and help you solve your problem. (You can see exactly what I mean in [this blog post](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).)

Comment: @Eric i just want an idea or hint about how can i accomplish this thing. i will manage the coding myself

Comment: Its just a hint.I m not from android.dont mistake if i am wrong. add a textwatcher to the edittext and find whenever text changes and search in an array, which you used to populate your listview and get the "index" of an item and scroll your list to that "index" position.

Comment: Hi tapan, Did you solve your problem?? Actually I have the same problem. can you help me out?? because your accepted answer is not helping much.

Comment: There's an answer marked as the answer, but... it really doesn't specially answer this question at all.  The link within the answer shows how you can change the position of the scroll, but... how do you jump down to a text value within a listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you get a chance to look at [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/scroll-to-a-position-in-a-listview)