# Android: Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollbar

[image]

I want to achieve this in list view and gridview.
Please Guide me.
On the long click of down arrow, i want to come to the end of the of the list.

Comment: Not necessary for list view or grid view only. Can be implemented on any layout.

Comment: had you create that view already ?

Comment: What i just want is a customized vertical seek bar which drags my list view up and down, and two buttons one on each side that also drag my list view up n down accordingly. Thats it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setSelection(index`), the listview display will jump to the index you want

```
downButton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

   listView.setSelection(LastPositionIndex);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

See this link also, may be related to you

[Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/scroll-to-a-position-in-a-listview)

EDITED

See this link, not  exactly what you want but similar, I think you will require custom listview for your purpose.

http://baziegar.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-listview/

Comment: main problem is to implement the scrollbar. The thumb of the scrollbar.

Comment: No Sorry. I want a simple implementation. Thats it.

Comment: I am afraid there isn't any simpler implementation other than custom view

Answer (score 0):

onClick the bootem button call this function

```
mListView.setSelection((mListView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1));
```

onClick top

```
mListView.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: What i just want is a customized vertical seek bar which drags my list view up and down, and two buttons one on each side that also drag my list view up n down accordingly. Thats it. Thank you.