# Preserving scroll position of PreferenceActivity across invocations

Tags: android

Let's say I have a `PreferenceActivity` (which I cannot convert to use Fragments for compatibility reasons). One setting within that `PreferenceActivity` is for the current application theme, which I would like to apply instantly when changing the preference by calling `PreferenceActivity#recreate()` to force recreating the activity (using the new theme).

Unfortunately, the activity contains so many settings that scrolling may be required. Upon recreating the activity, I would like to restore the previous scroll position to allow for a seamless transition from one theme to another.

Attemting to preserve the embedded `ListView`'s scroll position using `getListView().getScrollY()` in `onSaveInstanceState`, however, always returns zero.

Is there any way to get hold of the `PreferenceActivity`'s list scroll position and to restore it later on?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/645270) help?

Comment: @Keyser: Unfortunately, calling `setSelectionFromTop` with the previously saved `index` and `top` data does not seem to have any effect...

Comment: Check the other answers and comments. There should be something there :p

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to get 2 values:

```
final int firstVisibleItem = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
final int firstVisibleItemTop = getListView().getChildAt(0).getTop();
```

Then save them into some storage (Preferences or Intent's budle or somewhere else). To restore scroll position from those values:

```
final ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setSelection(firstVisibleItem);
listView.smoothScrollBy(-firstVisibleItemTop, 0);
```

Comment: Restoration may not work right inside onCreate, so getListView.post could be used to get job done.

Comment: I put the top bit in OnSaveInstanceState with outState.putInt("firstVisibleItem", firstVisibleItem);
  outState.putInt("firstVisibleItemTop", firstVisibleItem);
restored them in OnRestore, then did the SetSelection in onResume. Worked great, thanks!