# Add new items at top of ListView not working. Adds items to the bottom instead

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am facing some difficulties getting the addition of new items in a `ListView` to appear at the top of the `ListView`. However, when new items are added to the `ListView`, I want the current item to remain visible and the new items to be added above it.

To that effect, I followed the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/450534 and when that did not work too, I started experimenting a little.

*Also worth mentioning is that I am using the Pull to Refresh library by Chris Banes.*

Now curiously, when I add `paged` data below the last item in the `ListView`, all works well. But I am stumped why new items will not be placed above the current item and maintain the current position. This is what I have done so far (in the `onPostExecute()`):

```
// GET THE CURRENT LISTVIEW POSITION (USED TO MAINTAIN SCROLL POSITION)
int currentPosition = actualListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
Log.e("POSITION", String.valueOf(currentPosition));

View v = actualListView.getChildAt(0);

int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
Log.e("TOP", String.valueOf(top));

/*****  APPEND NEW DATA TO THE ADAPTER AND THE LISTVIEW     *****/
// CAST THE ADAPTER (AGAIN)
adapter = new NewsFeedAdapter(getActivity(), arrFeeds);

// SET THE ADAPTER TO THE LISTVIEW
actualListView.setAdapter(adapter);

// SET THE SCROLL POSITION
actualListView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition, top);

lv.onRefreshComplete();
```

This is the start of the `ListView` and this is what should still be seen after adding new items at the top (above this). I plan to show a small layout that shows how many new feeds are on top. Something like the Facebook app does now.

[image: Start Of the ListView]

But new items are added to the bottom of the `ListView` instead of at the top above existing items.

[image: New items are added to the bottom of the ListView]

Is there something obvious that I have missed? If you need me to add more code, please tell me and I will add it immediately.

Answer (score 3):

another alternative would be to add the item at 0 poisiton of the ArrayList which you are using to populate the adapter.

```
  your_array_list.add(int index, Object element) //Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
```

and after adding you can call the notifyDataSetChanged() on your listAdapter.

Please confirm if it works..

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried that method too. The problem (I suspect) is that I fetch all the data in a `for loop` in the `doInBackground()`. This code is to fetch Newsfeeds from the Facebook API. If the number of items was to be say, a constant 1, then I think your suggestion could work. I think that is the case at least.

Comment: Even if you try to fetch the Data in doInBackground of Asynctask still you would be setting adapter to the List and that adapter would be holding some List of custom objects?

Comment: If you mean a POJO, then yes. I have one that is used for the `ArrayList`. The class is called `NewsfeedData`. Do you want me to add a part of the `doInBackground()` as well?

Comment: ok i think i got your Point now....this means that you want he latest news feeds at the Top..For this you can sort your arraylist<newsfeed> according to the notification date....by implementing the Comparable interface....

Comment: Okay. Partial success this time with your suggestion. But that kinda reaffirms my first comment. It added just 1 feed to the top. And plus, did not maintain the position. Shows the new item when it should have stayed right where it originally was. :-(

Comment: No no. I do not want to sort. Once a set of data has been shown, and the user pulls down the ListView to refresh, if there are any new feeds on facebook, they should be added to the top of the existing item. But without scrolling to the top and showing the new items. No sorting necessary. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: then if you dont want to sort then my previous approach would work suppose you  get 3 new feeds on the then you can add them on 0th,1st and 2nd position respectively....nd then notifying the adapter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26319/discussion-between-karan-rana-and-ssl)

Comment: Nope. Still struggling. It still adds new items to the bottom of the list. :-(