# Android etsy StaggeredGridView library add load more in footer and pull to refresh in header

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh, staggered-gridview

How can I add loading indicator to display getting more items from server  on etsy StaggeredGridView's footer when scroll down the last item of StaggeredGridView

Also , I want to add pull to refresh in StaggeredGridView header

Answer (score 0):

For the load more in footer: I think you can use getView() method from your Adapter to know when the last item is shown on the screen, then, you have to load more elements to the list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

for the pull to refresh you have a lot of questions related and code in the net, for example: [Set up pull to refresh for Staggered Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315493/set-up-pull-to-refresh-for-staggered-grid-view)

Anyway, It could help if you post some code here with your question.

Hope this helps!