# Listview position is incorrectly retain after coming back to fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, pull-to-refresh

I create a list-view inside  my fragment . i use [**pull to refresh view**](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) in my fragment

when i click on list item a another fragment will load with `backstack`  .Before loading the new fragment i save details about list-view to restore the position of list view when coming back.

But when when i come back to first fragment the scroll position is not retained properly

I use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/1450401) to restore list position .

also i use the same solution for [endless scroll](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/) it works fine

Can anybody tell me what went wrong ???