# Android - Actionbar tabs and fragments save fragement state between tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an android app have four action bar navigation tabs on the top. And I have added fragment to each of them as this suggested. It worked.

```
// here I created an ActionBar Navigation Tabs from MainActivity   
public function initActionBar () {

    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    String[] tabs = { "test", "test1", "test2", "test3" };

    ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[0]).setTag("0");
    tab.setTabListener(new MainTabListener(new Testfragment()));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[1])
            .setTag("1");
    tab1.setTabListener(new MainTabListener(new Test1Fragment()));
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
}

public class MainTabListener implements TabListener {

    ParentListFragment fragment;
    boolean added = false;

    public MainTabListener(ParentListFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ft.replace(R.id.jokeFragment, fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(fragment);
        //ft.detach(fragment);
        android.util.Log.v ("main tab listener", "detached");
    }

}
```

Here is main code from TestFragment, and Test1Fragment

```
@Override

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    init();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_test, null);
    return view;
}

public void init() {

    Posts.getInstance().setUpdateInfo();

    list = (PullToRefreshListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.list2);
    list.setTag("first");

    list.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {

            try {
                load("0");
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    init2();
}

public void init2() {

    adapter = new JokeListAdapter(this.getActivity());
    adapter.posts = Posts.getInstance().posts0;
    list.getRefreshableView().setAdapter(adapter);

    footer = (RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater) this.getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.view_list_footer, null, false);
    footer.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    loadingMoreLogo = (ProgressBar) footer
            .findViewById(R.id.loadingMoreLogo);
    loadingMoreLogo.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    listener = new OnButtonClickListener();
    Button button = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadMore);
    button.setTag("loadmore");
    button.setOnClickListener(listener);

    button = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonJokeTag);
    button.setTag("tag");
    button.setOnClickListener(listener);

    button = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.buttonJokeRefresh);
    button.setTag("refresh");
    button.setOnClickListener(listener);

    Posts.getInstance().getDataFromDB(0);

    if (Posts.getInstance().posts0 != null) {
        adapter.posts = Posts.getInstance().posts0;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.getRefreshableView().setAdapter(adapter);

        if (list.getTag() == "first") {
            list.setTag("");
            list.getRefreshableView().addFooterView(footer);
            footer.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    isNext = false;
    load("0");
}
```

When switch tabs, I found one issue, the Fragment I added to the tab is from `ListFragment`, and I will load data while its created as following code, this init function will load all data from service, and update the listView, this time it will scroll to the top of the view. Now when I switched to another tab, and then switched back, this function called again, so the view is jumped to the top. I actually want to know, how to keep the state of the Fragment, so when I switched back, it still in the lastest position it did have. Thanks.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        init();

    }
```

I am looking for an solution avoid to use listView position trick [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview), is it able to save fragment state, so next time we can resotre it as it looks like `Activity` do? For now, it have to be ActionBar Navigation Tab + Fragments.

This app initalily created fro Android 2.3 and used TabHost, and now I am converting it to Android 4.0 Actionbar based one. In TabHost, it use `Activity` for each `ListView`, and now I changed them to Fragment. All source codes in github.com, my private repo, if you are willing to help, I can add your account, so you can git cloen it and review it anytime.

Comment: It's easier for us if you show all your code

Comment: Thanks, just added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has so many answers, look here for [complete rundown](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/). It uses the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and u must use the that if your doing it for Android 2.3

This August 2013 Google released the ActionBarCompat with lets you do this back to 2.1 devices.
(ActionBarSherlock is an old alternative to ActionBarCompat)

Read the first two pages here:
[vogella- Using the Android action bar (ActionBar) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

And of course the announcement:
[ActionBarCompat and I/O 2013 App Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html)

Comment: Thanks Erik, you are so quick, let me check it.

Comment: Hi, just checked it I saw it use TabHost, but in my application, I may have to use ActionBar Navigation Tabs, is there any way for this?

Comment: Updated my answer, there is some things you should know to save you time. it's impossible to get Android 4.0 Actionbar in older devices without this.