# Save a ListView scroll position when navigating from list to detail

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

i'm using a custom ArrayAdapter to show my listView ,i click on item and navigate to detail activitivity , all it's working fine , but when i go back to my listView it's getting scrolling to top, i'm using the master detail flow generated by Android ( i just costumized the listView and detailView )

here is my costum arrayAdapter :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem> {

private final Context context;
private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> values;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<DummyContent.DummyItem> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item , values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if(rowView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textViewTitre = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titre);
        TextView textViewSC = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.sc);
        textViewTitre.setText(values.get(position).titre);
        textViewSC.setText(values.get(position).sctitre);
    }

    return rowView;
}
public void refill(List<DummyContent.DummyItem> events) {
    values.clear();
    values.addAll(events);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and here is my ListFragment class :

```
public class EventListFragment extends ListFragment {

/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public EventListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), DummyContent.ITEMS);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
```

and my MainActivity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new LoadEvents().execute();
}

/**
 * Callback method from {@link EventListFragment.Callbacks} indicating that
 * the item with the given ID was selected.
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(EventDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        EventDetailFragment fragment = new EventDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.event_detail_container, fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, EventDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(EventDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}

class LoadEvents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Aficher le sabiler avant l'opreration
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EventListActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Wait...");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * recuperer la liste des events
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Creation des Parameteres
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // JSON string à partir du URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                AgendaIConstantes.URL_EVENTS, "GET", params);

        ..... processing here
                    DummyContent.ITEMS.add(item);
                    DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // masquer le progress dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_list);

        if (findViewById(R.id.event_detail_container) != null) {
            // The detail container view will be present only in the
            // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
            // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
            // activity should be in two-pane mode.
            mTwoPane = true;

            // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
            // 'activated' state when touched.
            ((EventListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.event_list))
                    .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview

Comment: i have already tried it , it's not working

Comment: Try something like this:
[Solution to Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/1927047%22Solution%20to%20Similar%20Question%22)