# Listview scroll position

Tags: android, listview

i have Listview with images and text and i can to show image and text with list.setOnItemClickListener method, when i click listview item then open new activity and i can to show  Details. on second activity i have One button (Go back) and i want when i click this button listview would be position which i clicked first time
for example if i clicked listview 5 items and then when i click Back button i want to this 5 item would be first position

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                journal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smalljournal);

                tittle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle);
                description = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.smallDescription);
                smalllink = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smalllink);
                DateTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.smallDateTime);
                smallstatID = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.smallstatID);
                String Stringjournal = journal.getText().toString();
                String Stringtittle = tittle.getText().toString();
                String Stringdescription = description.getText().toString();
                String Stringlink = smalllink.getText().toString();
                String StringdateTime = DateTime.getText().toString();
                String StringstatID = smallstatID.getText().toString();
                HideKeyBoadr();
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
                in.putExtra("KEY_journal", Stringjournal);
                in.putExtra("KEY_title", Stringtittle);
                in.putExtra("KEY_description", Stringdescription);
                in.putExtra("KEY_link", Stringlink);
                in.putExtra("KEY_pubDate", StringdateTime);
                in.putExtra("KEY_statID", StringstatID);

                String url = itemList.get(position).get(
                        MainActivity.KEY_image);
                if (url.endsWith("-c.jpg"))
                    url = url.replace("-c.jpg", ".jpg");

                in.putExtra("Bitmap", url);

                startActivity(in);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in,
                        R.anim.trans_left_out);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
```

second activity

```
BackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent in = new Intent(Result.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_right_in,
                    R.anim.trans_right_out);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

program working perfect but when i click back button  listview is showing again.....

Comment: check out [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)

Answer (score 1):

don't call finish(); on your first activity

Answer (score 0):

listView.setSelection(position); send selected row to top of the ListView.
listView.setSelectionFromTop(position, 20); this method also send selected row top of the ListView. But second argument (in this method 20) distance of the ListView`s top edge. (include padding)
If you neccessary to finish the first Activity you need to save the position of item and when back button clicked send saved position to your Activity. (Bundle, static class etc...)

Comment: no no i just want when i click back button  item witch i clicked first position

Comment: I think. you want to switch clicked item and first item postion?

Answer (score 0):

**IDEA**

Simply you need to do is to create second activity without calling finish(). When user clicks on the back button in second activity just call onBackPressed(); to resume first activity.

So do not use finish() method in first activity and use  onBackPressed() in secound activity.

**What you should do:**

In first activity:

```
 @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
           //your logic gose here
           // start new activity without finishing current activity
}
```

In new activity:

just call onBackPressed(); in second activity.It will finish the second activity and automatically resume the first activity.

```
BackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //call onBackPressed(); to resume privious activity.
            onBackPressed();

        }
    });
```

Comment: onBackPressed();  what is this . how i can to resume  previous  first activity ?

Comment: Yes same code but i have explained the idea.Try to understand and use the above code.

Comment: ok understood . do you can to show part code  or google link solution my problem ?

Comment: if you understood the above code you do not need any other example.thi is easy read the answer carefully and apply to your code.