# Android listView: scrollBy and touch event

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView. I call scrollBy(0, 100) method in a constructor. When user want to scroll this list by touch event list returns to previous (without scroll) position and after that scrolls normaly. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: AbsListView has a method scrollListBy(pixels_y) , maybe it works better for setting default scroll position. Edit: whoops, didn't notice it's API 19 method...

Comment: Yes, probably I used setSelectionFromTop.  I will check this on Monday and accept your answer then

Comment: I have the same problem. I've created a complex ExpandableListView including other ExpandableLists as some of its child elements and scrollListBy or smoothScrollFromTop doesn't work well. The only operation that moves to the correct position that I want is scrollBy (I don't now why), but I've the problem that when user touches the list, it returns to the pre-scroll state. Do you know how I can prevent this using scrollBy? Not the other operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restore ListView state when recreating fragment (or Activity) it is better to use ListViews's onSaveInstanceState()

```
// Save ListView state
Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();

// Set new items
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll position)
listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```

If you want just to scroll ListView programmatically use method [setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int,%20int)).
See the answers to this question [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)