# Getting active item of ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have made a horizontal listview with ArrayAdapter as in the picture below.

[image]

There will be always 3 items on screen. But there is a problem. I need to get which three items are on screen. With getView function, I can only get last activated item.

Is there a way that I can get which items are on screen ?

Comment: is center item always selected?

Comment: Center item will be selected if I can get which items are on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()

ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()

you may refer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview/3035521#3035521) as well

Comment: thanks in advanced. This was the function I am looking for :)