# How can I restore ListView scroll position in my code?

Tags: android, listview

How to save and restore ListView scroll position in my app?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    DBAdapter db;
    List<Matn> motoon;
    ListView lst;
    boolean isAll;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// save index and top position
int index = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = listview.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - listview.getPaddingTop());

// ...

// restore index and position
listview.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Try This

Comment: hey i tried this. it doesn`t work and shows force close.

Comment: for which reason force close...can u put your logcat..??

Answer (score 0):

```
Public void reset(Arralist<string> itemsList) { 

this.adapterList.clear();
this.adapterList = itemList;

notifydatasetchanged();

}
```

Create this method in adapter class

and call like this after `setadapter().`

```
yourAdapterRef.reset(itemList);
```

Try this way it will work.