# HorizontalScrollView w/ TextViews that when clicked, go to an activity and not always returns to the same area of the screen

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

There are  three horizontal pages.  When a TextView is clicked a second activity pops up and passes new data back to that specific TextView.  This works; however,  sometimes it doesn't go back to the same area of the 3 pages.  Is there something I can do to freeze the scroll?

Comment: Possible duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview). It's exactly what you need I think.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.