# How to save Scrolling state of a complex listview in a fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I am using a file explorer listview in a fragment.

But not getting how to save its scrolled state .

I searched Stackoverflow quora and google for last 2 days but didnt got any result.

My project support Api 14 +.

In my Fragment Explorer,

I am making onCreateview  and onclick like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist,container, false);

 //My coding stuff here

        lv=(ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adaptor);

        return root;
}
```

onclick is as follows:-

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
              lv=getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
             gtuMcaBean1= gtuMcaBean.get(position);
                                 lv.setAdapter(adaptor);
}
```

In my Fragmentactivity clas i call onBackpressed

```
    @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        // super.onBackPressed();
         if(pager.getCurrentItem()==0)//0 is item no for explorer view
         {
//My coding stuff here
        lv.setadaptor(adaptor);
         }
```

In my Mainactivity also i have an onbackressed which works when i come to fragment view frm an activity

```
@Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
        // super.onBackPressed();
         if(pager.getCurrentItem()==0)//0 is item no for explorer view
         {
//My coding stuff here
        lv.setadaptor(adaptor);
         }
```

Now i want to save the scroll state of Listview so if user presses back button it should display previous scroll view not from starting of ListView.

Thanx In advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/5193608)

Answered by ian

```
 // save index and top position
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - mList.getPaddingTop());

// ...

// restore index and position
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```