# How do I save state of activities instead of always having onCreate called in Android?

Tags: android

I would like my application to save state after it already has loaded once. For example in one of my activities I have a ListView. If the user scrolls it, and than switches activities, I wish for them to go back to the ListView activity and have the same scrolling position. I noticed that pressing the back button goes back to a saved version of the state. This is the exact kind of save I want (where it saves the state of the previous activity). Except I want to do this from anywhere in the application, not just when the back button is pressed... Please help me.

Comment: Try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/5688490/4018207

Comment: I am not looking to just save an activity with ListView. Also a map, etc.

Comment: @ JessThePest : At `onPause()` save all your data to shared preferences and restore all data on `onResume()` ..!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and store the values you want to save in `Bundle` object as name value pair.

```
  @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {           
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); 
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("position", 12); 
     savedInstanceState.putString("Name", "John");

           }
```

also you have to override onRestoreInstanceState() where you'd extract the values:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  boolean myPosition=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("position");
  String name= savedInstanceState.getString("Name");
}
```

see this link for help [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android)

Comment: I am trying to save a whole activity not just a few Strings and booleans :S

Comment: @JessThePest you have to save whole activity data like this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the `saveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods. The first one called near `onPause()`, the second called before `onResume()`. To save the state of a view, call `onSaveInstanceState()` from view.
For example, `listview.onSaveInstnceState();`
Here's a detailed article
https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-save-and-restore-the-scroll-position-and-state-of-a-android-listview