# How to maintain the ListView position while come back to previous ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I populate the list-view from `Sq-lite db.`Now my problem is that when i click on list-view item for going to next page and after that come back to list-view , I want the list to be scrolled to the same point that it was previously.Any idea how to do this.

This is my `list-view` method in

**onCreate()**

```
private void populateList() {
    descArray.clear();
    List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getAllDescriptions();
    for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc)
    {
        String strInspectorname = all_Post.getStringInspectorname();
        Log.e("strInspectorname "," = " + strInspectorname);
        descArray.add(all_Post);
    }

    if (adapter == null)
    {
        adapter = new AllPostAdapter(this, R.layout.allpostlist, descArray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else if (adapter != null) {

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter = new AllPostAdapter(this, R.layout.allpostlist, descArray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I tried this link [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview) , listView goes alwyas last position .

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps,

1. Store your First listview Position which was clicked somewhere in Database/Shared Preference.
2. Move to your 2nd listview.
3. When you come back to your 1st listview just simple Get that stored value of your 1st listview position.

4.
 **For a direct scroll:**

```
getListView().setSelection(YOUR_POSITION);
```

**For a smooth scroll:**

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(YOUR_POSITION);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to the next page just store listviews's scroll position by calling either getScrollY/ getScrollX depending on your listview orientation. When you come back again to this page restore stored position by calling either setScrollX/ setScrollY

Comment: I use your code lines but listview gets always scroll position is 0

Comment: you can try solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview?rq=1