# Orientation: restore ListView position that is inside a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I went trough a famous post in SO, [Maintain/Save restore scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)
but does not help me at all.

I have a ListView inside a Fragment, if I change the orientation, I would like that saveInstance Bundle will save my position.
I have

```
 private static final String LIST_STATE = "listState";
private Parcelable mListState = null;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    mListState = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable(LIST_STATE, mListState);

    }
```

and  does not matter if I put in OnCreateView or in onActivityCreated the following code

```
  if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
       mListState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LIST_STATE);
       listView.onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
```

the up position of the list is not restored at all.
I can easily see from the debug in Bundle that the debug recognize in the Bundle the position,

> AbsListView.SavedState{3d7562e0 selectedId=-9223372036854775808
>   firstId=25 viewTop=-38 position=5 height=717 filter=null
>   checkState=null}

I even tried to extract from the Bundle this position in an isolated way instead of all the values, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The solution is

```
  @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

mPosition2=listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

if(mPosition2!=0) {
    mPosition = mPosition2;
}

        if (mPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            outState.putInt(SELECTED_KEY, mPosition);
        }
        }
```

and in onCreateView

```
  if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SELECTED_KEY)) {
            mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_KEY);

        }
```

finally I have a loader that query a content provider at end of onLoadFinished( but you can put you just where you need)

```
  if (mPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {

        listView.setSelection(mPosition);
```

I have also tried listView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition)
but is not working at the moment, but never mind it works really well to me.

Answer (score 1):

add following code inside fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your interest, but if I call setRetainInstance(true) the ListView disappears if I change rotation