# How to move scroll of ListView on to the new data added in ListView in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I have a listview in which 5 data are visible to user.when I scroll bottom of listview and a progress bar at the bottom of listview is visible to me and server request is send at this point and 5 more data are added in data set, Here I want to make this new data visible to user when added in data set. i.e. move scroll position on new data set.

code:-

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && bBottomOfView) {
        Log.i("Listview", "scrolling stopped...");
        if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
            sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
            sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(CLastCountData.getInstance().getS_szLastCount());// convert int value to string /////

            Log.e(TAG, "Last Count::" + sz_LastCount);
            Log.e(TAG, "Record count::" + sz_RecordCount);

            loadmoreData();


        } else {
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, "No internet connection available", getActivity());
            m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
        }

    }

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);
                if (mSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                try {
                    int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("resultcode"));

                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kTRANSACTION_SUCCESS) {
                        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                            item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                            item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                            item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                            item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                            if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {

                                s_oDataset.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                        m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        arrayCount = posts.length();
                        int add = CLastCountData.getInstance().getS_szLastCount() + arrayCount;
                        CLastCountData.getInstance().setS_szLastCount(add);
                        Log.e(TAG, "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
                        m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);


                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use listView.setSelection(position of item you want to scroll)

Comment: but how to define position of item if data are coming from server .....may be it is 5 or 4 or 3

Comment: you have posts.length(). I think this is giving the total new item load count. if it is not then you can add a globel parameter for previous count.

Comment: if I implement listView.setSelection(position of item you want to scroll) if post.length() becomes 3 then what do I enter at position

Comment: m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
listView.setSelection(adapter.getCount()-post.length());

Comment: if view not scroll then you can try with this mListView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mListView.setSelection(index);
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to maintain the scroll position of your listview:

First off all you have to get the current child position of listview from below code:

```
// this code should be written before updating adapter in your listview
int lastViewedPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

//get offset of first visible view
View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
int  topOffset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
```

then after updating your data in adapter you have to call this:

```
listView.setSelectionFromTop(lastViewedPosition, topOffset);
```

Like in your code:

```
    Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);
                if (mSwipeRefresh.isRefreshing()) {
                    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                try {
                    int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("resultcode"));

                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == CStaticVar.m_kTRANSACTION_SUCCESS) {

int lastViewedPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

//get offset of first visible view
View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
int  topOffset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();



       JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                            item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                            item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                            item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                            item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                            if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {

                                s_oDataset.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                        m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setSelectionFromTop(lastViewedPosition, topOffset);

                        arrayCount = posts.length();
                        int add = CLastCountData.getInstance().getS_szLastCount() + arrayCount;
                        CLastCountData.getInstance().setS_szLastCount(add);
                        Log.e(TAG, "ArrayCount::" + arrayCount);
                        m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
```

Comment: where do I put that code before notifyseChanged or after

Comment: before adding additional items to your list just get the poistion of last scroll postion and after notifyseChanged  listView.setSelectionFromTop(lastViewedPosition, topOffset);

Comment: listview scroll does not moving

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview will help you