# How can I save the scroll position for my ListView

Tags: android, listview

I design an app that has 2 activity, first (all_activity) contains a listview using BaseAdapter. when a user clicks in one of the items it will start a new activity(Story_Detalies ) contains an information for the items in the listview.

I make the (all_activity) parent for the (Story_Detalies)activity  and by using this code in  (Story_Detalies) activity

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

it will show an arrow to go to the previous activity.

the listview has a lot of items so when a user clicks on the arrow I want the listview to be scrolled to the same point that it was previously.

And this is my code for listview in oncreate():-

```
    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisallflashcard);
   adapter = new AdapterAllQ(getApplicationContext(), rows, prgmImages2,stortype);
   listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getFirstVisiblePosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition()) to figure out which item is the first on screen. Next you can iterate over the children until you find the one corresponding to the first visible position, and use [`getTop()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop()) to figure out its vertical offset.

```
int position = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = listView.getChildAt(i);
    if (listView.getPositionForView(child) == position) {
        offset = child.getTop();
        break;
    }
}
```

You can save those values and use them on the way back to call [`setSelectionFromTop(position offset)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelectionFromTop(int,%20int)).

Comment: I have this issue   can't resolve method 'getPositionForChild(android.view.View)'

Comment: @Mi_Dhah sorry, the method is `getPositionForView()`. I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for correction, just to make sure where is the right place to put your code a

Comment: @Mi_Dhah Naturally it needs to be somewhere that you have access to the ListView and are aware of the appropriate points in the lifecycle where you want to use these methods. You will have to figure out the best way to integrate it.