# How to get a callback when a ListView finishes rendering after being attached an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I basically populate a `ListView lv` with an `ArrayAdapter` and I need to programatically `lv.smoothScrollToPosition(i)` only after it's rendered; otherwise, it will not work. The event I'm listening to is `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` to set the adapter to the listview.

How can I catch the moment at which is optimal to scroll the `lv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can work around for your situation. Using Handler, after you call notifyDataSetChanged or set adapter to your listview, you can use:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 200ms
        lv.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
      }
    }, 200);
```

Comment: I complemented the solution with this answer and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/2422833

Answer (score 0):

try judge position in getView method;

public @NonNull View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,
            @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

Comment: Please post complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using overriden function `getView` in your `ArrayAdapter`. You can check if position is equal to the no of items in your list.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if(position == yourList.size() - 1) {
       //do your work
       //it's better to make interface handle this call inside your Activity
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Here, the number of times it iterates only match the number of items rendered (which I don't know in advance), not the size of the list.