# Xamarin Forms ListView scrolled to top?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a InfiniteListView which extend ListView from Xamarin Forms.
I know when you on the last item in the list but how can i figure out if the user scrolled to the top of the list ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Xamarin Forms ListView does not expose a `Scrolled` event or `Position` property. So your only option is to use the `ItemAppearing` and `ItemDisappearing` events.

When you subscribe to these events, you can figure out if the first cell is appearing again, after it disappeared first. This does not actually give you a 100% correct outcome, since it can happen that only a part of the first cell is shown.

If you want a perfect check that you are at the absolute top, you will have to resort to a custom renderer:

- On iOS you can make use of the `tableView.contentOffset.y` property on the UITableView.
- On Android it's a little bit more involved, as there are multiple (but no straightforward) ways to achieve this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/6192895) for one possibility. This approach is originally meant for saving and restoring scroll position, so adjust it to your needs.
- Other platforms have similar ideas. Check which native control the Xamarin Forms renderer creates, and then search the internet for possible solutions for that specific platform.