# listview android scroll on some devices and doesn't scroll on the other

Tags: android, listview, landscape-portrait

**listview scroll on some devices Nexus_5x and doesn't scroll on Samsung galaxy tab 7**

I try everything on the internet :

this doesn't work !

```
// save index and top position
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - mList.getPaddingTop());

// ...

// restore index and position
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Link here

[Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)

also this doesn't work

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);  // your listview inside scrollview
lv.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

link here

[ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

My listView xml is

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        style="@style/ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonClear"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
```

landscape doesn't work , but portrait is just fine.

I don't understand why it's ok on some devices and even portrait mode but not the other ?

Answer (score 2):

To start with, its not always a good idea to nest a scrollable view in another especially when they are scrolling in the same direction, although in some cases there are not much alternatives. When I want to implement something like that say a recyclerview in a scrollview, I disable the scrolling behaviour of the recyclerview and make the size expand depending on the size of the contents

http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=33330388&ttl=How+to+put+RecyclerView+inside+NestedScrollView%3F

That is a link to where it is implemented. Study it so you'll get the idea. 
Goodluck