# How to retrieve the position where I left after going to another Activity, ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I'm doing this and is not working, I have researched all over the place but I can't find the right solution. I have researched about `onSaveInstanceState()`  but I can't get it to work too.

My problem is that when I scroll and press an item from the listview it opens ok, but when I go back it goes to the top of the listview instead of showing me the last item I was on.

I first declare an int position:

```
int position;
```

After that I get the position from my listview in my onCreate:

```
position = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

And after setting the adapter I'm setting the selection to the position of the listview:

```
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mListView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First override `onSaveInstanceState()` and save the scroll position. Then override `onRestoreInstanceState()` to load the scroll position and scroll the view to it.

Note that this will only maintain the scroll position while your app is running. If you want to restore the position when your app is closed and restarted, then you need to use `SharedPreference`. You should override `onPause()` to save the position in `SharedPreference` then override `onResume()` to load the position.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on Listview item of activity A, for Ex 5th position of the listview, now what I recommend is that you should store this value in the Preference and move to Activity B and when you return from Activity B to Activity A than just simply retrieve the position from the preference in `onResume()` method and just call the `yourListView.smoothScrollToPosition(YOUR_POSITION);`