# Preserving listview scroll position in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I read [How to maintain the position of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725011/how-to-maintain-the-position-of-listview)

That solution only works if the activity/fragment is not destroyed.  If it is, like with a screen rotation, I think you need to put the scroll position into a bundle in onSaveInstanceState.  Otherwise, when resuming the activity/fragment, the index will be 0 because it was not only stopped, but destroyed after rotating the screen.

So I saved the scroll position in my fragment's bundle in onSaveInstanceState and set the position in onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("scrollPos", listv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
int startIndex;
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
        startIndex = 0;
    else
        startIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("scrollPos");
    questionsLV.setSelectionFromTop(startIndex, 0);
    return v;
}
```

I see the index saved in onActivityCreated after I rotate the screen, but my listview still starts from the top; why?

Comment: put it in your oncreate method

Comment: you need to restore the position after the list has been populated, the problem is, in onActivityCreated the list is empty. Issue the setSelectionFromTop from a point later in our code when you are sure that the list has been initialized.

Comment: in oncreate I save the index.  in oncreateView before I set the adapter, then call setSelectionFromTop.  The debugger shows the saved index value, but the view it returns still starts at index 0.  See updated post.