# Hiding Image button when page scrolls in android

Tags: android

I have `btn_hide` button in my code.This button appear and disappear by click of a button(`btn_main`) as below code.

I want to implement to disappear `btn_hide` when page scrolling and touching any point of the page too.

Please help me.

```
    btn_hide.setVisibility(rootView.GONE);

btn_main.setOnClickListener(new onClickListner(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(btn_hide.getVisibility()==rootView.GONE){
                btn_hide.setVisibility(rootView.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                btn_hide.setVisibility(rootView.GONE);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: I'm not using FAB and I'm using eclipse

Comment: Where is _touch event_?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I dont have a touch event.Help me with a example

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement touch event on root view and for detecting scroll on scrollview you need to use below code

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

        int scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX(); //for horizontalScrollView
        int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY(); //for verticalScrollView
        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE SCROLL COORDINATES

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please post your error. You can also refer this link for scroll listerner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263053/android-scrollview-onscrollchanged

Comment: above `btn_hide` is in horizontal scroll view. I cant remove that. because of  above code that scroll view isn't scrolling any more. How to make scroll that horizontal view.( When I scroll the page button disappear This part is working)