# getScrollX() return wrong value, why?

Tags: java, android

`recList.getScrollX()` line returns always 0, even though `recList` is scrolled already by user.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            final RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userSettingList);

    horizontalScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {

                        int scrollX0 = recList.getScrollX(); //always returns 0, why?

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure it was scrolled in the X axis?  Vertical scrolling (up and down) is scrolling Y, so you'd use getScrollY().

Comment: sure, I am debugging and printing out

Comment: To be clear, your RecyclerView scrolls *left and right*?

Comment: i believe it's because scrollX() is a method from the view, not the recyclerView. on my app i set the Y position by setSelection. not sure how to do it with X.

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132370/android-listview-getscrolly-does-it-work

Comment: Thanks @avjr I found there fix. Storing total scrolled distances in a global variable.